# Draws the Highlight over the top of the tabpage

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, highlight, tabpage

i am using  TabControl in my windows form application (c#)

and

i want draw  the Highlight over the top of the  tabpage headers using hightlightcolor.

http://img4up.com/up2/83871411772596923665.jpg

thanks

Comment: can you include the picture of what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you. Just apply this below mentioned code in OnDrawItem Event of Tab Control

```
if (e.Index == SelectedIndex)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 4, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width - 6, e.Bounds.Height);
    backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, rect);
    string tabName = this.TabPages[e.Index].Text;

    TabPages[e.Index].BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    TabPages[e.Index].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

    TabPages[e.Index].UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    TabPages[e.Index].RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
    myFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    myFont = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    RectangleF r1 = new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + 1, e.Bounds.Y + 4, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 4);
    foreColorBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(tabName, myFont, foreColorBrush, r1, myFormat);
    // e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(rect.X + (GetTabRect(e.Index).Width - _imageLocation.X), _imageLocation.Y));
}
else
{
    myFont = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    backColorBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.CadetBlue);
    foreColorBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    TabPages[e.Index].BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    string tabName = TabPages[e.Index].Text;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 1, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width - 1, e.Bounds.Height + 1);
    myFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, rect);
    RectangleF r1 = new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 4, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 4);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(tabName, myFont, foreColorBrush, r1, myFormat);
    //e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(rect.X + (GetTabRect(e.Index).Width - _imageLocation.X), _imageLocation.Y));
}
myFormat.Dispose();
myFont.Dispose();
backColorBrush.Dispose();
foreColorBrush.Dispose();
```